# Android show random numbers in TextViews

Tags: java, android, android-studio, random

I want to generate random numbers from 1 to 9 and show each number in
a different TextView (It is for a sudoku)

I have nine TextViews.

```
private TextView textView1;
private TextView textView2;
private TextView textView3;
private TextView textView4;
private TextView textView5;
private TextView textView6;
private TextView textView7;
private TextView textView8;
private TextView textView9;

public void generateNumbers() {

    // Random numbers
    int numbers = 

    textView1.setText();
    textView2.setText();
    textView3.setText();
    textView4.setText();
    textView5.setText();
    textView6.setText();
    textView7.setText();
    textView8.setText();
    textView9.setText();
}
```

In some squares I need to show 3 numbers and in other squares 4 numbers

Comment: but they cannot repeat within a square? So you want a method that will return 3 (or 4) distinct random numbers between 1 and 9? And your question is how to generate them?

Answer (score 1):

```
 val numbers:MutableList<Int> = arrayListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
 numbers.shuffle()
```

Comment: Oneliner: `val numbers = (1..9).shuffled()` :)

Answer (score 0):

### Use Random class in Java.

```
import java.util.Random;

// Obtain a number between [1 - 9].

Random rand = new Random(); 
int random = rand.nextInt(9); //This will give value from 0 to 8 
random += 1; //This will give value from 1 to 9
textView1.setText(random);

//You can continue like this

textView2.setText(rand.nextInt(9) + 1);
textView3.setText(rand.nextInt(9) + 1);
textView4.setText(rand.nextInt(9) + 1);
......
```